# Query for last 8 week data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This query is for last 6 months and I need the same query for last 8 week. If any particular week doesn't have data then it should return 0 count. I need 8 weeks data in 8 rows, each row will be having 7 days data. I am not able to write the query, so please help me!

```
select monthYear, COUNT([Report No])
from
    (SELECT [Report No], monthYear=CONVERT(nvarchar(3), datename(month, CT_ReportedDate))+ ' ' + CAST(DatePart(YYYY, CT_ReportedDate) as nvarchar(4))
     FROM [Person].[dbo].[Reported_Crimes]
     where [CT_ReportedDate] &lt;=  DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) AND [CT_ReportedDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0) AND {CrimeName}
    ) as x
group by monthYear
order by DATEPART(MONTH,monthYear) asc
```

Comment: Which part of it are you stuck on?   What have you tried?

Comment: i haven't tried any think coz i don't know how to do

Comment: please can any one help me to write a query

Comment: What part specifically don't you know how to do?   I suggest you start by googling and learning about the elements in the query you have.   especially the `DATEDIFF` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you need the other conditions for but you find the 6 months in this part:

```
[CT_ReportedDate] >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
```

Change it to

```
[CT_ReportedDate] >= DATEADD(WEEK, -8, GETDATE())
```

This changes the condition to 8 weeks prior today